# Can CSS do a conditional max-width or min-width for objects themselves?

Tags: css

Without using JavaScript, is there a way in CSS to say something like "whitespace: nowrap" specifically for td but only if the td has a max-width of a certain size?

I know you can do @media to do css only for certain screen sizes. I want to have the css only apply when a particular object is a certain size.

Comment: This isn't possible with current CSS technologies. You will have to use Js or rethink your layout flowing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need JavaScript to do exactly what you want, but there is a possibility:

Let's say that you applied a class to some `<td>`s:

```
<td class="changed">...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td class="changed">...</td>
<td>...</td>
```

And you gave `.changed` a certain `max-width`:

```
.changed {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Then, you would be able to do what you want:

```
td:not(.changed) {
    /*Some styling*/
}
```

Comment: I think you mean class, not id -- id's must be unique on a page.